# Continuous deployment using Capistrano and Travis-CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app to a VPS using Travis after following [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/lukewpatterson/4242707), and I'm hitting a few problems. I generate the encrypted ssh key on my server like so:

```
base64 --wrap=0 ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64
ENCRYPTION_FILTER="echo \$(echo \"-\")\$(travis encrypt theodi/uk-postcodes \"\$FILE='\`cat $FILE\`'\" | grep secure:)"
split --bytes=100 --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=2 --filter="$ENCRYPTION_FILTER" ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64 id_rsa_
```

I then put the resulting encrypted vars into my `.travis.yml` file and put the reconstituted the private key `before_install` like so:

```
before_install:
  - echo -n $id_rsa_{00..30} >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64
  - base64 --decode --ignore-garbage ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64 > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

I'm then running `cap production deploy` after a successful build like so:

```
after_success:
  - "[ \"$TRAVIS_BRANCH\" == \"master\" ] && bundle exec cap production deploy"
```

But I'm still having no joy. The error I get on the Travis output (from Capistrano) is as follows:

```
INFO [5a729430] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/uk-postcodes/ on 162.243.77.171
DEBUG [5a729430] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/uk-postcodes/ )
cap aborted!
deploy
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:25:in `create_or_reuse_connection'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:173:in `ssh'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:126:in `block in _execute'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rvm1-capistrano3-1.1.1/lib/rvm1/tasks/capistrano3.rake:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/travis/build/theodi/uk-postcodes/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```

I've also tailed the `auth.log` on my server and I see the error `error: key_read: uudecode`.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong? (There is a certain amount of cargo culting involved in the first step, but I think I understand what's going on)

Comment: The keys you generated, are they for your machine, or the travis machine?

Comment: They're for my server. Travis generates small boxes for every test run, so it's impossible to do normal public/private key authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some updates to `travis` gem (CLI tool) that can simplify encoding.
I described a way of deploying apps from Travis via Capistrano on blog post: https://cowbell-labs.com/2014-03-06-capistrano-deploys-from-travis.html

Comment: Ah, cool. That sounds sensible. However, after a bit of fiddling (I had to remove the quotes from the `'$DEPLOY_KEY'` part of the decrypt command), I still get an `Authentication failed` error. I'm assuming this may be something to do with the fact that I'm on Capistrano 3?

Comment: I also used Capistrano 3. Is this error thrown when capistrano authenticates to server? If yes, it may be problem with RSA keys setup (`authorized_keys` file on server) - are you able to log in from your machine using this key?

Comment: Ah, I missed this vital bit of information: "Make sure to add the generated public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server." However, now I get an issue when cloning the repo from github: `Error reading response length from authentication socket. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: Ah, I've figured out what was going on, I needed to add the public key to Github. All sorted now. Thanks!